# Parsing string dates in ruby such as "28-May-10"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, strptime

I tried parsing using

```
Date.parse("28-May-10").to_s
```

Returns `0010-5-28` (which is 2000 years off!)

How can I get ruby to interpret the two digit year properly.

There are plenty of string to date conversion tricks out there on google but most handle digit months as opposed to "May".

Comment: I've got the right result - "2010-05-28", check you environment, make sure "require 'date'"

Comment: I required date and wound up with the same thing as the OP on Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Same thing with require date '0010-05-28'

Comment: I've got my result under ruby 1.9.3p125

Comment: maybe thats why i'm still on ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0] (Latest before the leap to 1.9)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer `Date.strptime` for this task:

```
require 'date'
puts Date.strptime("28-May-10", "%d-%b-%y") #2010-05-28
```