# Ruby parse date string

Tags: ruby, date, date-format, date-parsing

I need to parse a date string mentioned below into a `Date` object.

Is there a built in function in Ruby that would parse something like the string `"December 09, 2011"` to a `Date` of 2011-12-09?

Answer (score 41):

`Date.parse` is already mentioned.

I prefer `Date.strptime`. This methods is a *reverse strftime*.

`Date.parse` is a (maybe good) guess, with `Date.strptime` you can parse each date, when you know which format you expect.

Example:

```
require 'date'
puts  Date.strptime('December 09, 2011', '%B %d, %Y')
```

Or if you have [another format where `Date.parse` fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727898/parsing-string-dates-in-ruby-such-as-28-may-10):

```
require 'date'
puts Date.strptime("28-May-10", "%d-%b-%y") #2010-05-28
```

Answer (score 20):

Do as below using [`Date::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'date'
Date.parse('December 09, 2011').to_s # => "2011-12-09"
```